# Закрывается файл python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке открыть файл через проводник в два клика, он на секунду разворачивается и сразу же закрывается, скрипт рабочий, всё должно быть ок, но у меня он не может открыться, никаких ошибок, просто закрывается, подскажите в чём проблема

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот если что сам файл, попробуйте, может у вас получится понять проблему https://t.me/pirateincryptochat/32158

ПРИ ПОПЫТКЕ ОТКРЫТЬ ФАЙЛ ЧЕРЕЗ CMD или IDLE ПИШЕТ ВОТ ЭТО
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сам скрипт внутри, посмотрите может станет что понятнее, извините за тупые вопросы...просто у всех он открывается, а у меня не работае
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Напишите для начала, как именно вы его открываете. (команды, код и т.д.). Какое у файла расширение?

Comment: Ну сколько я понял в проводнике два клика

Comment: Да, просто в проводнике в два клика, всё верно

Comment: используйте командную строку

Comment: выполняется и закрывается, это нормальное поведение. Что должно быть-то?

Comment: Он не должен закрываться, это скрипт в котором должны задаваться параметры для его дальнейшей работы, и так далее, а он даже не открывается

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что запуск файла *.py выполняется двумя кликами? Запустите его через комендную строку, как уже советовали, или из среды типа IDLE.

Comment: Я уже попытался, выдаёт ошибку, посмотрите пожалуйста в вопросе, я написал что выдаёт

Comment: ну вот бери ошибку и исправляй

Comment: Обратите внимание на строку `"ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'requests'`. Если ее перевести, то станет ясно, что не найден модуль `requests`. Значит, его нужно установить - `pip install requests`

Comment: Я новичок, мне дали скрипт который должен работать, я не разбираюсь в этом...по этому написал вам с просьбой помочь...потому что сам я её не решу

Comment: придется научиться разбираться. Здесь не начальная школа.

Answer (score 2):

Эта проблема происходит, так как в два клика открывается в виде программы а не как редактор. Если используете официальный IDLE для питона то просто нажимаете правой мышкой и выбираете "open with IDE" или вроде того (это решение первой проблемы). А вторая проблема в том, что вам надо установить нужную вам библиотеку. Напишите в консоли (т.е. cmd): `pip install <название библиотеки>`.

Answer (score -1):

```
pip install requests
```

через cmd сделай

Comment: а что нового привносит ваш ответ в сравнении с предыдущим?